# Is there a way to create an enabled Knowledge Base in Dialogflow from Backend?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create knowledge base in Dialogflow from backend using NodeJs. I am being able to create knowledge base using createKnowledgeBase(). However, the created knowledge base is by default disabled in Dialogflow interface and i have to manually enable it in dialogflow. I want to create an enabled Knowledge base when i create one. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same thing and facing the same issue. did you find any workaround for this? I have below via APIs. 
1. creating the knowledge base
2. adding a document
problem I am facing is once job is done via APIs, its not enabling the knowledebase, I have to goto dialogFlow dashboard and enable it manually + Adding response $knowledge.answer[1] manually too. can we do this both programatically. so that there is no need to goto dialogFlow dashboard screen